# Prove that $E(y)=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $x\sim f_{x}$ where $f_{x}$ is a continuous PDF. We say that the distribution of $x$ is symmetric around $m$ if for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f_{x}(m-a)=f_{x}(m+a)$. Let $y=x-m$.

How do I prove that $E(y)=0?$

So far, I just have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yf(y)dy$$ $$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-m) f(x-m)dx$$ $$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x) f(x-m) - (m) f(x-m)dx$$

I'm not sure what to do next. Any suggestions?

Comment: Split the integral in two! $\int = \int_{x<m} + \int_{x>m}$.

Comment: @dafinguzman I don't understand. Please explain in detail.

Comment: Oops! I found an error in your reasoning which I was overlooking. I will correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: @dafinguzman Okay. Also please point out to my mistake,

Comment: It is not really a mistake, only a confusion. The thing is, you are using an $f$ you know nothing about (the PDF of the variable $y$). You should use $f_x$ instead, because you know its symmetric property.

Comment: The question should really separate more clearly random variables such as $X$ and $Y$ from real valued arguments of functions and integrals, such as $x$ and $y$. To use systematically the latter for the former is not acceptable in a mathematical context. The same remarks apply to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

You want to know the expected value of the random variable $y$ which depends on the variable $x$. The thing is, you don't know a priori what is the PDF of $y$, you only know about the PDF of $x$.

The expected value of a function $h(x)$ is calculated using the variable $x$'s PDF, like this: $E(h(x)) = \int h(x)f_x(x)dx$.

So, instead of your first expression, write $E(y) = E(x-m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-m) f_x(x)dx$.

The idea of splitting the interval of integration is a good one: $f_x$ has the same values to the left and to the right of $m$, so it makes sense to integrate separately from $-\infty$ to $m$ and from $m$ to $\infty$.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-m) f_x(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{m} (x-m) f_x(x)dx + \int_{m}^{\infty} (x-m) f_x(x)dx.$$
Now change variables inside the integrals, $y=x-m,\, dy=dx$ , to get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} y f_x(m+y)dy + \int_{0}^{\infty} y f_x(m+y)dy.$$
and use $f_x$'s symmetric property on *only one of the terms*, so that the values where $f_x$ is evaluated mirror those appearing in the other integral. For example, applying it in the first term yields
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} y f_x(m-y)dy + \int_{0}^{\infty} y f_x(m+y)dy.$$
Finally, change variables once more in the first term, $z=-y$, to get
$$-\int_{0}^{\infty} z f_x(m+z)dz + \int_{0}^{\infty} y f_x(m+y)dy =0.$$

Comment: So, I know that $x$ is symmetric from the question? The way the question is worded is very confusing to me.

Comment: @OGC I added more explanation, hope it helps

Comment: So far, I have this $\int_{-\infty}^{m}y f_{y}(y) dy + \int_{-\infty}^{-m} y f_{y}(-y)dy$ but not sure how I can get $0$.

Comment: @OGC after changing variables you should have got $\int_{-\infty}^0yf_x(m+y) dy+ \int_{0}^\infty yf_x(m+y) dy$

Comment: @OGC Note that the subscript $x$ in $f_x$ is not an argument of the function! it is part of the "name" of the function, so it stays as it is.

Comment: I still don't understand. Could you add one or two steps to the answer. I know that $y$ is symmetric around $0$.